# How do I fix this error? Error: Opening the cache

Tags: apt, software-sources

How do I fix this error?

```
Error: Opening the Cache 
 (E:Type 'http://deb.opera.com/opera/' is not known in line 1 in source list
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list, 
 E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. 
 This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

I just want the error gone. I was trying to download Opera and can't do it obviously! I don't like the Firefox or Chromium browser, so I wanted to try Opera, which failed.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list.disabled
sudo apt-get update
```